# Forget client certificate setting for specific domain (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, x509

**Using:** Chrome 67.0.3396.99

1. Our webserver implements X.509 client authentication. The certificates are offered through the PKCS#11 interface; we connect a smartcard (in this case: Yubikey 4), the browser prompts for the certificate selection and PIN.
2. We disconnected the smartcard and visited the authenticated domain (say, `localhost:8000`) to observe the behavior of the webserver (in a local development environment).
3. The webserver correctly refused to serve the request.
4. However, Chrome now does never send anymore the certificates while visiting `localhost:8000`, even if the smartcard is connected.

The following did not resolve the problem:

- Clearing all site data through the developer console;
- Resettting site preferences to their defaults (through `chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?`);
- Rebuilding the webserver.

Any pointer where I can clear this state from Chrome would be greatly appreciated. As a temporary fix, we run the server at a different port but this is not an option on the long term. As this scenario is very plausible to also happen in production.